# NSColorPanel to hex issue?

Tags: nscolor, nscolorpanel

I have an NSColorPanel that I am inputting RGV values:

```
NSColorPanel * sharedPanel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
[sharedPanel setTarget: self];
[sharedPanel setAction: updateColor:];
[sharedPanel orderFront: self];
```

The color panel display and I set this value:  r66, g114, b170

By my calculations, this should be #4272AA. I use the following code to convert to hex:

```
- (void) updateColor: (NSColorPanel*) panel
{
    NSString * hexString = [panel.color hexadecimalValueOfAnNSColor];
    NSLog(@"%@", hexString);
}
```

Which logs out `#345d9a` (not what I would expect).

I'm using the following method from directly from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1576/_index.html) to convert the color to hex:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface NSColor(NSColorHexadecimalValue) 
-(NSString *)hexadecimalValueOfAnNSColor;
@end

@implementation NSColor(NSColorHexadecimalValue)

-(NSString *)hexadecimalValueOfAnNSColor
{
    float redFloatValue, greenFloatValue, blueFloatValue;
    int redIntValue, greenIntValue, blueIntValue;
    NSString *redHexValue, *greenHexValue, *blueHexValue;

  //Convert the NSColor to the RGB color space before we can access its components
    NSColor *convertedColor=[self colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace];

    if(convertedColor)
    {
        // Get the red, green, and blue components of the color
        [convertedColor getRed:&redFloatValue green:&greenFloatValue blue:&blueFloatValue alpha:NULL];

        // Convert the components to numbers (unsigned decimal integer) between 0 and 255
        redIntValue=redFloatValue*255.99999f;
        greenIntValue=greenFloatValue*255.99999f;
        blueIntValue=blueFloatValue*255.99999f;

        // Convert the numbers to hex strings
        redHexValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", redIntValue]; 
        greenHexValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", greenIntValue];
        blueHexValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", blueIntValue];

        // Concatenate the red, green, and blue components' hex strings together with a "#"
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@%@%@", redHexValue, greenHexValue, blueHexValue];
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have entered coordinates in different color space (probably device's, since on my Mac, #4272AA in color space of my display when converted to calibrated color space produces almost the same result, #345C9A).

To change color space in `NSColorPanel`, click tiny rainbow button. `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace` corresponds to "Generic RGB" selection — since your get-hex method uses calibrated, you need to use the same if you want to get the same numbers back.

[image]

A tiny bit of warning: this piece of code from developer.apple.com is harmful.

- When people say hex codes to each other, it is almost universally assumed to mean the same color as HTML/CSS would produce. This means hex codes must be in sRGB color space, since web standards dictate to use sRGB whenever color space information is omitted/missing.
- Apple's "Generic RGB" (NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace) is **very different** from sRGB and native color spaces of most modern displays. Your problem just demonstrates how huge that difference is.
- Most of displays in the world are manufactured to match sRGB as best as possible, and high quality displays of modern Apple's devices are particularly good at that.
- This leads to somewhat surprising conclusion: *if need those hex codes to produce same colors as in HTML, using `NSDeviceRGBColorSpace`, however wrong that is, instead of `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace` gives much better results*. You can easily verify that fact by entering the same color coordinates in Device, Generic and sRGB color spaces and comparing to what HTML page in Safari produces.
- If you need correct and guaranteed match with hex codes used in Web, you will have to do color conversion to sRGB manually, since `NSColor` does not support reading components for any color profiles other than Device RGB and Calibrated RGB.